# Pass on KeyPress to textbox with Form.KeyPreview

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a Winform with a textbox.

If the user presses a key on his keyboard, the text should be go into the textbox.

To test if the textbox has focus, I process the following 2 events:

```
Private Sub Textbox1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Textbox1.LostFocus

    _bFocusLost = True

End Sub

Private Sub Textbox1_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Textbox1.GotFocus

    _bFocusLost = False

End Sub
```

I have set the Form's KeyPreview to True so that I will be notified about the keypress before any control:

```
Private Sub frmMain_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

    If _bFocusLost Then
        Me.Textbox1.Focus()
    End If

End Sub
```

This works fine, however the first key goes into Nirvana because the Textbox doesn't have the focus yet.

How could I pass the first key on to the textbox?

Thank you!

Comment: Firstly, as the documentation clearly states, an application developer should not be handling `LostFocus` or `GotFocus` or calling `Focus`. The events you should be handling are `Leave` and `Enter` and the method you should be calling is `Select`.

Comment: Your `_bLostFocus` field is completely pointless and there's no point handling any events either. You can already determine whether that control has focus without any of that, using either `If Not Me.TextBox1.Focused Then` or `If Me.ActiveControl IsNot Me.TextBox1 Then`. You don't even necessarily need to test anything anyway, as you can just call `Me.TextBox1.Select()` and it will have no effect if the control already has focus.

Comment: As for the issue, it sounds to me like you need to determine whether the right control has focus and, if not, remember that for the `KeyPress` event. In the `KeyPress` event handler, if the right control was not focused, you can determine what the input character was and then set the `SelectedText` appropriately. I'll flesh that idea out into an answer if and when I get time.

Comment: Your comments are just perfect. It works! Thank you!

Comment: This work for me:     Private Sub frmMain_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
        If Not Textbox1.Focused Then
            Textbox1.Select()
            Textbox1.AppendText(e.KeyChar)
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: You need just `Textbox1.AppendText(e.KeyChar.ToString())` and nothing else, if you simply want to append a char (`ToString()`, `Option Strict On` would let you know that) to the existing text.

Comment: I also want to put the focus to the textbox, therefore I use "Select" if it's not focused yet.

Comment: It doesn't change much. The `If Not Textbox1.Focused` is not needed anyway. What you probably want is `e.Handled = true` after `AppendText()`, otherwise, if the Focus is on another TextBox, it'll also get the first char. Also, probably substitute `.Focus()` with `Me.ActiveControl = textBox1`

Comment: Don't call `AppendText`. That assumes that the caret will be at the end of the existing text, which is certainly not guaranteed (unless it is for your specific app). That's why I said to set `SelectedText`. Doing so will behave just like keyboard input, i.e. it will insert at the current caret position and it will replace any text that is currently selected. You should also consider that control characters may be entered too, e.g. backspace and delete.

Comment: In my case, the text should be inserted at the end. But in general, you're right. Thank you!